# Error Invalid username or password in azure AD B2C when add OIDC:ClientId on restAPI before trigger Login-NonInteractive in custom Policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an issue when I add client Id to check the user to our DB in azure AD B2C. I need to check that for validating the user login with correct db and migrate them (my app using multiple client Id)

This is my claims provider

```
<ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>REST API User Migration Via Legacy IdP</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="UserMigrationViaLegacyIdp">
          <DisplayName>REST API User Migration Via Legacy IdP</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://473b-180-249-185-45.ap.ngrok.io/v1/CheckUserMigration</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">ApiKeyHeader</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
            <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="x-api-key" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_RestApiKey" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isMigrationSuccessChecked" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

and this for the Self Assert Local account sign in

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">false</Item>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <!-- Check user migration on REST API -->
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="UserMigrationViaLegacyIdp" ContinueOnError="false" />
            <!-- Initiate a normal logon against Azure AD B2C -->
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

The endpoint for rest API is working fine and the client id is already get in endpoint. but when the step into login-NonInteractive that will return error.

When I try to remove the {OIDC:ClientId} the user can login again without any error

please help me about this

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re overwriting clientId and breaking the one set for login-noninteractive.

Try

```xml
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="api_client_id" PartnerClaimType=“client_id” DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" />
```